# SQL PHP count data between two date group by day and show each day record

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have problem on my sql code, 
Here is the code:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(CASE WHEN ItemState = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS C1,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ItemState = 3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS C2,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ItemState = 5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS C3,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ItemState = 7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS C4,
COUNT(CASE WHEN ItemState = 10 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS C5,
DAY(LastUpdate) AS Day
FROM purchasehistory
WHERE ItemID=77
AND LastUpdate BETWEEN "2017-10-25 00:00:00" AND "2017-10-30 23:59:59"
GROUP BY Day
ORDER BY LastUpdate
LIMIT 5
```

The count statement is work, but the result is not what I wanted

[Here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKr4x.jpg)

[image]

It should show five record where day equal 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30

But when c1, c2, c3, c4 and c5 are all equal 0 it didn't show the row instead of showing all 0

How to solve the problem?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: That is because in that case there was likely no row returned so it can't show you any data.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Given that you tagged php, seriously, seriously consider handling the display aspect of this problem in that.

Answer (score 2):

I find that a simple way to fix this in many cases is to move some filter conditions into the `case` conditions:

```
SELECT SUM(ItemID = 77 AND ItemState = 1) AS C1,
       SUM(ItemID = 77 AND ItemState = 3) AS C2,
       SUM(ItemID = 77 AND ItemState = 5) AS C3,
       SUM(ItemID = 77 AND ItemState = 7) AS C4,
       SUM(ItemID = 77 AND ItemState = 10) AS C5,
       DAY(LastUpdate) AS Day
FROM purchasehistory
WHERE LastUpdate >= '2017-10-25' AND LastUpdate < '2017-10-31'
GROUP BY Day
ORDER BY MIN(LastUpdate)
LIMIT 5;
```

This assumes that there is at least one product on each day.

The more typical solution is to use a `LEFT JOIN` -- and that can be better performance-wise.  I just find the above approach to be a quicker way to get the desired results.

Some other notes:

- MySQL treats boolean expressions as numbers in a numeric context, with "1" for true.  You don't need a `CASE`.
- The ANSI standard for string delimiters is single quotes, not double quotes.
- The date logic is simpler using dates.  No need to worry about when the last transaction is on any given day.
- Why are you using `LIMIT 5` if you are selecting six days worth of data?